# TexShop says "No pages of output"

Tags: texshop

I'm trying to use *TexShop* after not using it for a bit, and am getting "No pages of output" and no PDF at all. LyX works fine (if that's relevant). Where should I begin looking for a solution. *TexShop* worked once (a while ago) on my system, and I'm not sure what might have changed since I last used it.

I'm getting no error messages and the log is perfectly uninformatave:

```
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Naturally I've tried reinstalling, but to no avail.

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: First question: is there any actual typeset content in your file? A pdfTeX run can happily produce no PDF if there is nothing to see!

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes. In fact for old files, the PDF content is unchanged from the last time it was rendered, and TeXShop will happily open whatever PDF was created when it last worked, but will do nothing to it.

Comment: What is the TeX distribution you're using?

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which produces this result on your system. That way, we can determine whether the problem is the code or the installation.

Comment: @fpast: MacTeX. Everything is uptodate (according to TexLive Utility. (And, again: LyX works fine.)

Comment: @cfr: Anything at all.

Comment: Does the `engine` tab of TeXShop's Preferences mention `/usr/texbin`?

Comment: @fpast: Yes, it does.

Comment: My last attempt at it before I'm at a complete loss as well: have you trie to desinstall TeXShop completely (also the TeXShop folders in `~/Library/Applications Support` and `~\Library/Preferences`) and then reinstall it?

Comment: @fpast: It might be messed up ghostscript. Testing now.

Comment: What are the first few lines of the log file? If you are compiling using latex, can you compile using pdflatex? (That should avoid any ghostscript issues.) Can you compile successfully from the command line?

Comment: @cfr: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`

Comment: Can you compile from the command line?

Comment: @cfr: What should a healthy ghostscript configuration look like? I think that may be my issue. I'll reinstall that and see.

Comment: pdfLaTeX does not use ghostscript as far as I know. That's why I suggested using pdfLaTeX rather than LaTeX for testing. You haven't said if you can compile from the command line or not.

Comment: @cfr: No idea how. But other tools (like LyX) are working fine, if that's relevant. And — now it works — TexShop was just dumb about finding ghostscript.

Comment: If that was really the problem, then it cannot have been true that the problem manifested with 'anything at all' since pdflatex does not, itself, use ghostscript. (But if you include images in postscript format or whatever, then ghostscript might be used by e.g. `graphicx` for on-the-fly conversion.) An MWE might have enabled people to figure this out without all the trappings of mystery.

Comment: @cfr: The MWE above produces the behavior; and reinstalling ghostscript fixed the problem.

Comment: That document does not require that ghostscript be installed at all if you compile with pdflatex. Indeed, I just removed ghostscript entirely from my system and compiled that MWE with pdflatex. As expected, it worked fine. What I can't do is use the latex route and get a PDF. (I can compile to .dvi, but not convert to .pdf.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by reinstalling Ghostscript.